# Is there a way to switch between io.js and node using a tool such as n or nvm?

Tags: node.js, nvm, io.js

I've used tj's [n](https://github.com/tj/n) for a while to switch between different node versions. I was wondering if anyone ran into a way to make it switch between io.js and node.js?

Comment: Yes it is. Just follow the instructions: https://github.com/creationix/nvm#usage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nvm allows you to `nvm install iojs` or `nvm install 0.12`. If already installed you can switch with `nvm use iojs`. They added iojs-support in January/Febraury.

**EDIT:**

Currently I prefer [TJ's](https://github.com/tj/n) `n` since it's al lot leaner and has less issues with os roles or similar. Do `n 0.12.7` or `n io latest` for iojs